# Stackoverflow error in regex after compiling clojure to a jar file

Tags: java, regex, clojure, babashka

I have a script written in **Clojure** using **babashka** that does some text processing. It works fine if I run it with `bb` command. But when I compile it to a `.jar` file and run using `java` command I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3789)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4618)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4672)
    .....
```

I was able to identify that the problem is caused by this `\s(?=([^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)` regular expression. Which I use to split a string by whitespaces excluding the ones inside quoted strings like that (`"a string that is not splitted"`).

How do I need to update that regex so it would work in **Java** after compilation to a `.jar` file?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue by running the Clojure script with `clj` or `lein`? What version of Java (e.g. `java -version`) are you using to run the Jar file?

Comment: I'm using `Java 8` to run it. And my script consists of a few files so I'm not sure how to properly run it with `clj` or `lein`

Comment: Please add precise code and sample data to repro